# Why .htaccess and a2enmod not working on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created an Elastic Beanstalk App and Env. It is PHP webserver on Amazon Linux. It has to host a ReactJS application built using `npm run build`.

I have also created AWS Pipeline which takes code from CodeCommit, Builds and Deploys it. Since it's a webserver, my App also needs an .htaccess file which I have tried to handle in `buildspec.yml` file as `cp .htaccess.default build/.htaccess`, but `.htaccess` does not work.

What I think the problem is that Apache's rewrite mode is OFF I am trying to turn it ON through `buildspec.yml` file. I tried to put command `a2enmode rewrite` and `service httpd reload` in different sections of `buildspec.yml` but no luck so far. The build crashes.

Here is my `buildspec.yml`.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
install: 
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10 
    commands:
    - apt install a2enmod    # <---- Build crashes, exit code 127
    - a2enmod rewrite        # <---- Build crasehs
    - service httpd reload
pre_build:
    commands:
    - npm install 
build:
    commands:
    - npm run build
    - cp .htaccess.build build/.htaccess 
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*' 
  base-directory: build/
cache:
  paths:
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
```

How can I get .htaccess to work on this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing wrong with `buildspec` syntax. But as a good practice, for public assets like `.htaccess`, you should keep it inside `public` folder of your ReactJS App. No need for `cp .htaccess.build build/.htaccess` or enabling apache rewrite module.